# Can some one please suggest me a good email inbox to use in selenium automation test execution

Tags: selenium-webdriver, email

We have some test cases to validate email body content after triggering some emails from our test system.
Previously we used UI automation with Gmail and Yahoo, but as we are running our test in different servers (Different IP address) Gmail and Yahoo are asking for the two-factor authentication and human verification which we can't handle from our test automation.

Also we cant use `Javax.mail` as the SMTP ports are blocked from our firewalls.

So could some please suggest a good email inbox to continue our test without any interruptions.

Comment: I found this is valid situation. Request to all community members, advice the improvement instead of only devoting the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solution :

- Honestly there could be multiple solutions
- **Solution** working for me is:

  - I simply use emails with my official domain for automation
  - Hence, no blocking email & hurdle got eliminated
- Email client for **email verification or confirmation**:

  - I make a use of `email` & `imaplib` **python library**
  - It will provide multiple methods for you to interact with your inbox and emails inside using exposed APIs
- **Nice, clean and secure way** to get raid of email interaction to extent automation reach